# SCCM Reporting - "Report Builder click-once application does not exist on the report server"

Tags: ssrs, sccm-2012

I (and my manager) would like to be able to create custom reports in SCCM 2012 SP1 through the Configuration Manager Administrative Console from the comfort of our workstations. Unfortunately, if you click the 'Create Report' button you get the following error:

 
 `The Report Builder click-once application does not exist on the report server 'SCCMReportingPoint.ad.contoso.com'. Ensure that the report builder application manifest exists on the server and try again.`

[image: Report Builder click-once application does not exist]

If I attempt the same process on our SCCM server (SCCMReportingPoint.ad.contoso.com), the Configuration Manager Administrative Console correctly starts ReportBuilder and I get the Create Report Wizard.

I have done the following in an attempt to resolve this issue without success:

- Installed both ReportViewer 2012 SP1 and ReportBuilder 3.0 on my workstation
- Tried starting the Administrative Console as an administrator
- Changed the `HKLM/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/ConfigMgr10/AdminUI/ReportingReportBuilderApplicationManifestName` registry key from `ReportBuilder_2_0_0_0.application` to `ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application` as per this TechNet post.
- Looked through Reporting Services log (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles\ReportServerService__10_28_2013_00_00_33.log`) on the SCCM server for errors. I did not find any.

I'm at a loss. I would really like to be able to setup custom reports without having to get our DBA involved (he is a busy man). Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: If you have report builder installed, can you navigate to the report server url and open, edit, and save a report?

Comment: @BigHomie - Yeah. We ended up just using the web interface for all our reporting needs but this was back at $JOB-1 so onto a different set of intractable problems. Thanks anyway.